# Split String to single variables between separators

Tags: c++, string, split

I am trying to find a more elegant / less memory intensive way to split a char array by separators.

The char array : "192.168.178\nWiFiSSID\nWiFiPassword\n123"

My idiot way of splitting:

```
void convertPayload() 
{
qrData = (char*)mypayload;

String ssidtmp = qrData;
ssidtmp.remove(qrData.indexOf("\n"), qrData.length()+1);
EEPROM.writeString(ssidAddr,ssidtmp);
EEPROM.commit();

String passtmp = qrData;
passtmp.remove(0, passtmp.indexOf("\n")+1);
passtmp.remove(passtmp.indexOf("\n"),passtmp.length()+1);

EEPROM.writeString(passAddr, passtmp);
EEPROM.commit();

String modulenrtmp = qrData;
modulenrtmp.remove(0, modulenrtmp.indexOf("\n") + 1);
modulenrtmp.remove(0, modulenrtmp.indexOf("\n") + 1);
modulenrtmp.remove(modulenrtmp.indexOf("\n") , modulenrtmp.length());
int modNRINT = modulenrtmp.toInt();

EEPROM.write(moduleNraddress, modNRINT);
EEPROM.commit();

String ftptmp = qrData;
ftptmp.remove(0, ftptmp.indexOf("\n") + 1);
ftptmp.remove(0, ftptmp.indexOf("\n") + 1);
ftptmp.remove(0, ftptmp.indexOf("\n") + 1);
ftptmp.remove(ftptmp.indexOf("\n") , ftptmp.length());

EEPROM.writeString(ftpAddr, ftptmp);
EEPROM.commit();

EEPROM.writeBool(configModeAddr, true);
EEPROM.commit();

//indicate QR succesfully read
blinkBurst(2, 300);

ESP.restart();
}
```

As you can see I'm creating unnecessary Strings. What would be the right way to do it?

Cheers and thanks for your time!

Comment: You can use [std::strtok](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/byte/strtok)

Answer (score 1):

If you can edit `mypayload` you can use [std::strtok](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/byte/strtok)

```
void convertPayload() {

String ssidtmp = std::strtok(mypayload, "\n");
EEPROM.writeString(ssidAddr,ssidtmp);
EEPROM.commit();

String passtmp = std::strtok(nullptr, "\n");
EEPROM.writeString(passAddr, passtmp);
EEPROM.commit();

String modulenrtmp = std::strtok(nullptr, "\n");
int modNRINT = modulenrtmp.toInt();
EEPROM.write(moduleNraddress, modNRINT);
EEPROM.commit();

String ftptmp =  = std::strtok(nullptr, "\n");
EEPROM.writeString(ftpAddr, ftptmp);
EEPROM.commit();

EEPROM.writeBool(configModeAddr, true);
EEPROM.commit();

//indicate QR succesfully read
blinkBurst(2, 300);

ESP.restart();
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply! 
I just looked into it... It seems I could have googled a bit more ...